# Mapbox Tile Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, mapbox

While using mapbox maps, When we move the map, zoom-in and zoom-out to locations, after a certain point of time, the new images of map stop loading.
When i checked on console, the new tiles server requests stay in pending state.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

This also happens with the map in the sample map at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/
Just keep using it for a while and make rapid zoom-in and zoom-outs in the map.
Note that this is not an internet bandwidth issue, and i am also using the paid version of mapbox.

My configuration is:

Browser: Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m

OS: Windows 8 Pro

Mapbox version: 2.2.2

Comment: We're currently having the same trouble at our company. Specific people's computers (so far windows+chrome only) can reproduce this problem consistently. Most other's can't no matter how hard they try. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce this, however I had a similar issues with the tiles not loading. It turned out to be due to a div I had covering part of the map area. It seems like mapbox can detect if there is an object over the map area and will not load the tiles.

Just an idea, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just diagnosed this in our office. Updating Chrome to the most recent version (48) OR disabling Tampermonkey solved the problem. As per https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3198, other extensions may also trigger the same Chrome bug.